# Keep Django user through template rendering

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-templates

I have template upload_file.html

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

And a view:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, renderer_classes
from rest_framework.renderers import TemplateHTMLRenderer, JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(('GET', 'POST'))
@renderer_classes((TemplateHTMLRenderer, JSONRenderer))
def upload_file(request):
    print(request.COOKIES)
    print(request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES:
        # some logic here
        return Response(data={'ok': True}, status=200)

    return Response(template_name='upload_file.html')
```

So I logged into system and sending GET request to this view, I see request.COOKIES are set with session, user is me.
After I submit files - I see that POST request is sent to my view, request.COOKIES are set with session, but user is some AnonymousUser.
How can I preserve my user through this two requests?
Django 2.2.6, DRF 3.9.4

Comment: Is @api_view from django rest framework?

Comment: Yes
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

Comment: Is this an ajax view? If so, you shouldn't be using Django's version of `HttpResponse` and `render`. You should be using DRF's.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I've edited my question, but problem still remains. Also now I have another error - "Returned template response with no 'template_name' attribute set"

Comment: You shouldn't be returning a response from a DRF API endpoint with a template. It should be in the same format as the successful path which in your case is JSON.

Comment: @schillingt sorry, didn't quite get it. You writing about GET or POST response for this view? Could you provide a code example?